# Guard::RSpec error: No cmd option specified, unable to run specs

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, guard, specifications

After upgrading to guard 2.6.1 guard stopped executing specs for changed file

```
13:27:09 - INFO - LiveReload is waiting for a browser to connect. 
13:27:09 - INFO - Guard::RSpec is running 
13:27:09 - INFO - Guard is now watching at '[path to project]'
13:27:13 - INFO - Running: spec/models/[some_model]_spec.rb
13:27:13 - ERROR - No cmd option specified, unable to run specs!
```

My bundle is

```
Using guard (2.6.1)
Using guard-livereload (2.3.0)
Using guard-rails (0.5.3)
Using guard-rspec (4.3.1)

Using rspec-core (2.14.8)
Using rspec-expectations (2.14.5)
Using rspec-mocks (2.14.6)
Using rspec (2.14.1)
Using rspec-rails (2.14.2)
Using rails (4.0.4)
```

Answer (score 60, accepted):

You need to update your `Guardfile` and add the [`cmd` option](https://github.com/guard/guard-rspec#options).

> Guard::RSpec 4.0 now uses a simpler approach with the new `cmd` option
>   that let you precisely define which rspec command will be launched on
>   each run. **This option is required** due to the number of different ways
>   possible to invoke rspec, the template now includes a default that
>   should work for most applications but may not be optimal for all.

This is how looks my Guardfile:

```
guard :rspec, cmd: "bundle exec rspec" do
  # ...
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternative answer in case of using [Zeus](https://github.com/burke/zeus) to speed up test execution

```
guard 'rspec', cmd: "zeus test" do
  #
end
```

Make sure you start **Zeus** before using **Guard**

```
> zeus start
```